# Datadog could not invoke kafka_consumer python check constructor

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, datadog

I am getting the Loading Errors while integrating Kafka with [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-kafka-with-datadog/).

```
could not invoke 'kafka_consumer' python check constructor. New constructor API returned:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/kafka_consumer/kafka_consumer.py", line 54, in __new__
    kafka_version = cls._determine_kafka_version(init_config, instance)
.
.
.
Python Check Loader:
        could not configure check instance for python check kafka_consumer: could not invoke 'kafka_consumer' python check constructor. New constructor API returned:
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

The config file is base on an [example.config](https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/master/kafka_consumer/datadog_checks/kafka_consumer/data/conf.yaml.example)

kafka_consumer version is `2.6.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the issue by updating the version, the updated version of kafka_consumer is (2.8.3) and it seems working fine.

**Verification:**

Run this command

```
sudo datadog-agent status
```

and then look for the following section in the status output

```
    kafka_consumer (2.8.3)
    ----------------------
      Instance ID: kafka_consumer:e7d2850bfd10c874 [OK]
      Configuration Source: file:/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/kafka_consumer.d/conf.yaml
      Total Runs: 79
      Metric Samples: Last Run: 90, Total: 7,110
      Events: Last Run: 0, Total: 0
      Service Checks: Last Run: 0, Total: 0
      Average Execution Time : 140ms
      Last Execution Date : 2021-05-24 02:41:46 UTC (1621824106000)
      Last Successful Execution Date : 2021-05-24 02:41:46 UTC (1621824106000)
      metadata:
        version.major: 0
        version.minor: 10
        version.patch: 2
        version.raw: 0.10.2
        version.scheme: semver
```

[Script to update version](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/versions/upgrade_to_agent_v7/?tab=linux)

```
DD_AGENT_MAJOR_VERSION=7 DD_API_KEY=your_API_key DD_SITE="datadoghq.com" bash -c "$(curl -L https://s3.amazonaws.com/dd-agent/scripts/install_script.sh)"
```